# SVN: update of the svn_auth_file on the fly

Tags: svn

The list of SVN users comes from another system.
So each time this list is updated, the SVN server must take into acount the updates.
To do so, we receive, on a regular basis, the list of (login/password) of the SVN users allowed to access the repository.

With a shell we recreate the file `svn_auth_file`:

- creation of the `svn_ath_file_temp` using command `htpasswd -cmb <login> <password>`
- replacement of the `svn_ath_file` in the `csvn/data/conf` directory

Questons:

- Is this method correct?
- Is Apache/SVN able to take into account a new svn_auth_file on the fly (even when users are working on the repository?
- Is it necessary to stop/start Apache/SVN?
- Does this operation could lead to the following error:

  `- [Mon Apr 28 08:30:20 2014] [error] [client 206.16.105.224] user 17948: authentication failure for ".../tags": Password Mismatch`

Comment: Maybe LDAP-auth (and SSO in common) will be better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Short answers on your questions

- Yes
- Yes
- No
- Yes, it can and **must**. But this is client-related error. Any SVN-client stores used even once auth-credentials locally in order to reuse it later. When you'll change username|password for known to client URL, it doesn't mean it know about this and shows the old data.

For Windows-world they (auth. details) stored in $APPDATA$\Subversion\auth folder, one subfolder for each auth-type

```
Subversion\auth>dir /B
svn.simple
svn.ssl.client-passphrase
svn.ssl.server
svn.username
```

For http and https repositories `svn.simple` used, one file per host (I have more than one repository on Assembla with different URL, but only one file for https://subversion.assembla.com:443). In order to re-authenticate successfully file of host on client must be removed and re-created on login or credentials must not be stored at all and used every time in any command, which require authorization

```
Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
```